# Na vlues in vectors to do QQplots in R

Tags: r

when I am doing QQ plot on R it gave me errors because of the NA in the data set, I do not want to remove them from the data set but I need a code to ignore them while doing the plot?

Comment: Perhaps you can use `?na.omit` - a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) would help to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you want to plot x and y, and y contain some na's you can use

```
   which(!is.na(y))
```

to find the index of the y's that are not NA. You can then do the plot by

```
   plot(y[which(!is.na(y))]~x[which(!is.na(y))])
```